# Is it possible to keep many relations in one table column?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I use Entity Framework code first and I have problem because EF creates the `Event` table with two reference keys, one for class `ObjectOne`, and another for class `ObjectTwo`.

Is it possible to keep values of Id in one column `Event.ObjectId` and the type of relation in properties `Event.Type`?

I can do following mapping (in which I have only one column for FK). Is it possible to not create FK in database, because now I must add value that exists in `ObjectOne` table and `ObjectTwo` table and it's not a solution for me):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectOne>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Events).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.ObjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectTwo>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Events).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.ObjectId);
```

Sample classes:

```
 public class ObjectOne
{
    public int ObjectOneId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectTwo
{
    public int ObjectTwoId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}


public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class AddEvent : Event
{
}

public class Updated : Event
{
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a **horribly bad idea** to have a single column that references once `TableOne` and another time `TableTwo`. Don't do this. What's wrong with having **two separate, focused** FK columns? It's a much cleaner design this way - you can have **actual referential integrity** in place (something you cannot do with the other approach)...

Comment: Hehe I know that looks nasty, but I saw something like that in the source code of one company and they made it in nHibernate and I am curious is it possible to configure it with EF. I think they use this solution because they have one Event table and about over one hundred objects related with this event table, and now you have to choose 100 FK keys or 2 columns? Honestly I really don't know  good solution in this case, maybe you can propose something?

Comment: In that case, you need to have the two columns / properties, but you cannot establish any relationships - neither on the database level, nor in EF (since that FK column could reference any one of 100's of tables...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such *polymorphic associations* are generally considered an anti pattern, see Bill Karwin's [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). However, there may be situations where they get inevitable (or too practical to stay puritan). Bill Karwin is kind enough to recommend an implementation if you still want to use them. You should read the book for all the details but the heart of the matter is this diagram:

[image]

(where Comment has the role of your Event table, not to be confused with the Event table in the diagram!!).

In the base table all primary keys of tables that are associated with `Event` are collected.

With Entity Framework another approach is possible (although not really feasible with the number of tables you wish to accommodate): you can subclass `Event` in `OneEvent`, `TwoEvent` etc., where `Type` is the discriminator, and associate `ObjectOne` with `OneEvent`s, `ObjectTwo` with `TwoEvent`s, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for naming my problem. I put this book on my list;) Regarding my problem I can do what you introduce in the picture -> then I use Table-Per-Type hierarchy but it's very inefficient(query) or do like you described with this subclasses for Event class.