# How to configure an entity foreign key with a discriminator value?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Suppose I have the following three tables:

```
Products
- Id
- Price

Categories
- Id
- Date

Descriptions 
- Type
- Id
- Description
```

Descriptions is used for Products and Categories. That's why we have the column Type which is the discriminator. For example, for products Type=1 and for categories Type=2.

What would be the appropriate way to map these relationships using code first? I see one option with creating an abstract Description class and child CategoryDescription and ProductDescription classes using TPH. Is there any other option?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13212140/861716) for your options. TPH is OK.